# JQueryValidation with custom message and custom method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to do a form validation with jQueryValidation plugin. I have defined custom message for the field and also I have a custom method validation.

It looks like it always shows the custom message and ignore the custom validation error message.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("strlength", function (elemVal, element) {
    if(elemVal.length > 5) {
      return true;      
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, 'Enter atleast 6 characters');

    $("#sampleForm").validate({
    messages: {
        "firstname": "Please enter the firstname"
    },
        rules: {
        "firstname": {
        required: true,
        strlength: true
      }
    }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Enter Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value=""/>  
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have create the sample code here https://jsfiddle.net/manianprasanna/xhq8xtuk/14/

Comment: Why do you have a custom method when you can just use the standard rule `minlength: [5]`?

Comment: It's just for illustration purpose only, I actually have to do some other business logic there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `messages` for specific `validator`. Define `firstName` as `object` which will accept keys as your `validation` parameters.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.validator.addMethod("strlength", function(elemVal, element) {
    if (elemVal.length > 5) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, 'Enter atleast 6 characters');

  console.info('testing');

  $("#sampleForm").validate({
    messages: {
      "firstname": {
        required: "Please enter the firstname"
      }
    },
    rules: {
      "firstname": {
        required: true,
        strlength: true
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>Enter Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xhq8xtuk/15/)

Comment: Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?. @PrasannaManian